# convert special characters in XML to UTF-8 in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with my XML. When the tag values have special characters, I need these special characters to be converted to UTF-8. Do we have in C# any name space for handling this?

Comment: What "problem" do you have, exactly? It would really help if you could explain what you're trying to do, what your code looks like at the moment, and what happens.

Comment: Please be more specific about "special characters" - may be give an example. Do you mean xml entities with this like &gt; for the ">" character?

Comment: XML is generated by another system and due to special charecters like &, ', etc., in it I cannot process this XML to a webservice call which is again an another system which returns me an error message stating bad XML. I have to validate the XML at my end I was able to do this with a simple XMLTextReader, but now my requirement is that if I found a bad **XML line** due to these special chars. I have to convert them (say I have _&_ in between start and end tags, I hvae to convert only this & to UTF-8) to make the XML a valid one.                Sorry, for my late response

Comment: I should get this working in .net framework 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2008/02/writing-xml-with-utf-8-encoding-using.html

Look at the first comment for an alternative

Comment: I need to validate an XML which is already present on my disk and if it has any bad line, basically due to special charecters like &, I have to identify this sp. ch. and convert only it to UTf-8, so that the xml is good again

Comment: This is a really late reply! '&' isn't invalid because it's not UTF-8. It's invalid because XML has special characters. '&' is one. What you need is this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Comment: XML has many text encodings like UTF-8 and UTF-16. '&' is a special character regardless of the encoding. (I reread you're question today that's why its a late reply)

Comment: xml.Replace really solves my problem, but for now I have done the same in the originating system (in Delphi not is C#). Anyway thanks for ur help